# Unit test hook prestashop 1.7

Tags: phpunit, prestashop, hook

I would like to know if there is a technique to test a hook without doing a whole process. Example with the hookActionObjectAddAfter I would like to test it without having to make a complete command as a client would do.
Is it possible ? There is unitary testing?

Thank you in advance

Comment: There is no way, or at least not that I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you created a test.php file at the root of your site, put this code:

```
require(dirname(__FILE__).'/config/config.inc.php');

Hook::exec('actionObjectAddAfter', array( array('object' => $params)));
```

And in your browser, call the page yourdomain.tld/test.php

Regards

Comment: Thanks for your answer
But how to recover a valid $ params variable and example to make tests as if it were in real conditions?

Thank you so much

Comment: Try with : $param = new Order($id_order);

Comment: Big thanks !
I am not used to prestashop and I found no information on the subject even in the prestashop documentation.
Good game !